# how to know the read status of send an email in windowazure sendgrid

Tags: asp.net, email, azure, sendgrid

I am using window azure cloud service and send-grid service for sending email in my Asp web  application. Is there any way provided by send-grid in c# that the read/open status of email.
I know this feature provided by send-grid but i am unable to find it in code part.Please help any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our web API:

http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/index.html
http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/statistics_advanced.html

Here is some example code:

http://sendgrid.com/blog/using-sendgrid-with-visual-studio-2013-preview-for-windows-8-1-development